# is there other way to manage SQL Server CE Database V3.5 Sp2 besides visual studio 2010?

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

The manager that is built in Visual Studio is bad, really. Is there any other way to manage the SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 databases? I tried SQL Server Management Studio Express SP4, but it doesn't work. Appearently it only supports V3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (Express) supports 3.5 SP2 and you can supplement with my add-in: http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: this is a url to download it :) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b

Comment: there is a problem with this approach, i have already SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer installed, when i try to install express its not possible, this is really stupid , i mean the express supports and the full version dont. i installed the Express to a seperate machine but this is not very unconvenient :(

Comment: how do u get the full management studio to work with ce databases ? i have SQL Server 2008 R2. i dont have any option in the connect dialog to a sdf file, only "Database Engine, Analysis Services, Reporting Services and integration services". or there is anything i need to download?

Comment: Install SSCESqlWbTools-ENU.msi from your SQL Server media